# Is it possible to store one specific Django model/Postgresql table on another sever?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, models

Django natively stores all the content associated with it's models to one server. What if you wanted to store one specific Django model on another server? Is there something you can change in the settings.py to make this happen?

The problem I'm having is that for django apps like [django-messages]: http://files.arnebrodowski.de/software/django-messages/Documentation, the tables can get really large. When the app is installed, it natively creates a table on the original server, however, I'd like for it to have it's own server else where. What are my options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the FineManual(tm), with a quite readable link (labelled "multiple databases") in the upper half of the doc's front page.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @brunodesthuilleirs thanks for the quick reply, the problem I'm having is that for django apps like: django-messages: http://files.arnebrodowski.de/software/django-messages/Documentation/, the tables can get really large. When the app is installed, it natively creates a table on the original server, however, I'd like for it to have it's own server elsewhere. What are my options?

Comment: Please follow the link above and _read_ what is written. There's a fully fledged example of how to map apps or models to a specific connection.